# KH1 Traverse Town Candles?

Tags: kingdom-hearts

I'm talking about the puzzle in traverse town where you have to put out all four candles to open a chest. I know I have to use blizzard, but every time a put out a candle, one reignites. The others don't reignite, just one. How do I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you need is to cast Blizzard on them one right after the other, and they shouldn't reignite. They only reignite if you are trying to hit some of them out. Also, there may be a bit of timing related to it, so you might need to do it kind of fast. If you stand in the right spot, you can get at least 3 at once (I've gotten all 4 before, but it is trickier).

Comment: I tried that, didn't work. I also have hit all four at once, there is always one that reignites

Comment: I don't think you do, but maybe try breaking all the chairs too? Blizzard is all you should need to do though...

Comment: I can confirm that you absolutely can do it with just Blizzard.  It may help if you wait for them all to reset if you mess it up.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you might think you didn't get them all but check the chest. I tried over and over again thinking I didn't do it, but then I went to the chest and it opened right up.